# How do I play Nocturne as a solo top?

Tags: league-of-legends

In league of legends, most people say Nocturne is a jungler, but I'd like to know if its possible to play him as a solo top.

Comment: This type of question is not the best fit for this site. It has no definite answer and responses are likely to be based largely on opinion rather than fact.

Comment: @Shaun: I disagree. While mundane and poorly worded, this is a great question for Arqade. Most of the top League of Legends questions are of a similar, subjective nature. Just because an answer is not in the form of an almanac-query doesn't mean it's not grounded in fact. As of November 2012, it is a _fact_ that Nocturne is an inferior top-laner compared to many other top laners, and there are articulable reasons why.

Comment: @ChristopherBerman You're bringing up a discussion we [resolved in meta a while back ago](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/league-of-legends-question-quality-contest). :)

Comment: @Shaun: The topvoted answer in that meta discussion is exactly my argument for why this question is reasonable and acceptable (even if the question-author in this particular case has apparently not done a wit of research herself). As user badp quotes, "Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions." Gamei's answer below is clearly based one experience: Nocturne has a difficult time escaping ganks, for example. This is a brute fact of the champion, and the nature of top lane. If the discussion in meta was resolved, it was resolved in my favor, not your's.

Comment: @ChristopherBerman Indeed. Did I say anything in my previous comment to indicate otherwise? :) I'm merely pointing out that you are disagreeing with an old comment that we've since come to a resolution on as a community. You'll note how my answer on that question was downvoted into the negatives. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the tenor of your post. All's swell then!

Answer (score 4):

Nocturne's sustain from his passive is not on the same level as sustain from other tops such as Vladimir, Olaf, Irelia, Lee Sin, etc. This is the first negative for him: he would lose trades vs any of the more reliable "normal" top champions.

Additionally, Nocturne's ability to sustain revolves around him autoattacking continuously to lower the CD on his passive. On top of that, the passive heals him based on how much AE dmg his next attack does. These two issues combined will have your lane pushed to their tower 24/7, which means you are open for ganks even if you are you vigilant about warding. Since most junglers have gap closers, it is difficult to retreat from their tower in top lane to yours even if you start moving as soon as your ward sees the enemy jungler.

Essentially, even if you are winning vs your laning opponent(which is already unlikely!), Nocturne's kit is such that you are left wide open to being ganked - repeatedly.

For the reasons outlined above, and probably some I am missing as well, Nocturne works best in the jungle where his passive sustain can be used freely without having to deal with the negative aspects of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's probally not the best idea. He will likely auto-push the lane with his passive. Push too far and you can get (easily) ganked